# Converting the Select Case with To and Is to c# problems

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am convertng vb.net to c# 2010 as my job, and none of the automatic tools I have can succeed completely.   In special example, this case:

```
'searchString is a string paramter from a long method
Select Case searchString
   Case "paid"
      'Do something long here
   Case "oaaaaa" To "ozzzzzz", "maaaaaa" To "mzzzzzz"
      'Do other long code
   Case Else
      'other long code
End Select
```

I am mostly java developer before this, so not great with c# and none with vb.net.  I do not understand the "oaaaa to ...." part and this part is not converting.  Can you please point me to right place to find the c# version of this?

Comment: I don't know if the formatting is just off, but I find the question incomprehensible.

Comment: I am sorry I did not see that the code was formatting as not code.  I formatted code now is it possible to answer now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a direct equivalent in C# but you can easily achieve the same semantics (with more readable code!) using the following:

```
if(searchString == "paid") {
    // do something here
}
else if(
    searchString.IsInRange("oaaaaa", "ozzzzzz") ||
    searchString.IsInRange("maaaaa", "mzzzzzz")
) {
    // do other long code
}
else {
    // other long code
}

public static class StringExtensions {
    public static bool IsInRange(this string s, string lower, string upper) {
    if(String.Compare(lower, upper) > 0) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
    return String.Compare(s, lower) >= 0 && String.Compare(s, upper) <= 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no direct C# equivalent of the `Case "xxx" To "yyy"` syntax. I suppose the closest translation will probably be an `if`/`else if`/`else` stack:

```
if (seachString == "paid")
{
    // do something long here
}
else if (((searchString.CompareTo("oaaaaaa") >= 0) && (searchString.CompareTo("ozzzzzz") <= 0))
         || ((searchString.CompareTo("maaaaaa") >= 0) && (searchString.CompareTo("mzzzzzz") <= 0)))
{
    // do other long code
}
else
{
    // other long code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't seem to have the concept of Case ... To.  See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y(VS.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y%28VS.80%29.aspx).  The C# example says "This language is not supported".

Comment: C# definitely supports switch statements and case. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: switch {case is the C# equivalent of VB.NET's SELECT CASE

Comment: I didn't say that C# doesn't support switch statements.  Only that it doesn't directly support VB's concept of "Case ... To".

Comment: +1 Because what you've written is correct, C# doesn't have the concept of `Case... To` so you don't deserve -1.

Answer (score 0):

bitwise has the answer, but here is the translated code (it's just like javascript):

```
switch (searchString){
   case: "paid"
      'Do something long here
      break;
   case: "oaaaaa" To "ozzzzzz", "maaaaaa" To "mzzzzzz"
      'Do other long code
      break;
   default:
      'other long code
      break;
}
```